# In qtp,Sometimes, properties used for a webelement click doesnot work for the same click in another instance

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, qtplugin

For clicking a webelement I used properties: html id , html tag and index. And it worked successfully. And after a series of steps, I am trying to click the same webelement with same properties in same action or test.. But it doesn't work..

I am using uft 12.02

And sometimes a click or any operation which was working fine doesn't work next time when I run it. It shows "Cannot identify the object"...

Because of this I have to always unnecessarily rework on properties each time 
I am really confused about this kind of variation. Please help me out...

Comment: My wild guess would be `index` would be the reason. Try to identify object w/o `index` and give it a try.

Comment: @ Manishchristian thanks for that... i think index was the issue..

Comment: Lesson learned: Avoid using index whenever possible.

Comment: Yes.. will take care of that.thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F12 key press in a browser would display all the properties of that object when highlighted through an arrow(pointer) symbol in the pane. Using index identifier is highly discouraged and should be used as the last resort. Instead, use descriptive object identification if the property value changes during the course of execution. There has to be some pattern behind it which has to be studied. Kindly post more details about the object.

Using descriptive object recognition

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_descriptive_programming.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was using index for all the clicks thinking  index is the prime property . I removed index and prioritized other properties .